# GeoServer 2.20 - view only list of layers in a specified store

Tags: geoserver, layers, filter, sorting

Is there any way to view only the layers from a specific store in GeoServer (v 2.20)? I can't find anything online and I don't see any way to do this in the interface. The layer list shows everything from every store.

Comment: You could hide/show specific workspace by creating new user and role, if that works for you

Comment: interesting idea..but I don't see how to set the visibility of a workspace to a role?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best you can do is to filter the layer list.

[image]

Search is not limited to any field so you may get too many layers on the list. The list can also be sorted by any field by clicking the title of the field so that "sf" comes before "sfdem".

Answer (score 1):

To only show specific workspace, first create a new role (*test_role* in this case) under **Security** -> **Users, Groups and Roles**.

Next, create a new user (*test_user* in this case) and assign the newly made role to it.

[image]
Now, go to **Workspaces** -> select your workspace(s), and select the **Security** tab. Give Admin access to the newly made role.

[image]

Now login as the **test_user** and you'd only see the workspace(s) which the role has permission to.